# Save button in Activity of android application?

Tags: java, android, save

I know that this question has been resolved in many other threads for example: 
[Saving Android Activity state using Save Instance State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state)
I know that the onSaveInstance(Bundle bundle) method is called, but it is always called from the system. I would like to call it when the user presses a button. The only problem as far as I know is that you don't have the reference to the Bundle that is needed to store your bundle.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you need to save your application state, why do you want to use that method and a Bundle? Can you not persist it using [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) and then load them on resume?

Comment: I would like to add a button "Save & Exit" to my game. So the user can choose when to save the state. I practically gave up on doing this and planned to write the bundle created into a file. So I came to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598248/how-to-serialize-a-bundle. The user making the question has the same problem. Even there was suggested to use share prefernces as an option. I think it nearly the same effort for me now that Have already implemented createBundle method.

Comment: The effort might be similar apparently, but with the preferences you have much less to worry about. Depending on what data you're going to save I suggest that you consider using the preferences instead of a file. If it's only a bunch of native types I think it would be a better choice.

Comment: Thank you, preferences seems the android way of storing this kind of things.