# Data Structures similar to Bundle in Android?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, data-structures, synchronization

Hi I am working in on a General sync app, which take take data from client app and store it in Appengine. I am doing server side persistence using Entity classes. I was thinking are there similar classes to Bundle and hashMap class where almost any kind of primitive data can be stored and then saved on AppEngine??
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily serialize Bundle and store it on GAE as a byte array inside an Entity.

Comment: K.. Thanks and For those who want to know how to serialize Bundle check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598248/how-to-serialize-a-bundle)